# Login failed due to client TLS version in Automation Account

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-runbook

I am facing an issue in Python  runbook in Azure Automation Account.

Error

> connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',pyodbc.Error:
> ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Reason: Login failed due to client TLS version being less than
> minimal TLS version allowed by the server. (47072) (SQLDriverConnect);
> [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Reason: Login
> failed due to client TLS version being less than minimal TLS version
> allowed by the server. (47072)')

Script

```
    import pyodbc
server = 'servername.windows.net'
database = 'DB'
username = 'someuser'
password = '**'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT DB_NAME()")
        row=cursor.fetchall()
        print(row)
```

Comment: Aside... there's no `PORT` connection string property in ODBC Driver x for SQL Server. If you need to specify a port number other than the 1433 default you include it in the `SERVER` property, e.g.: `SERVER=tcp:serverNameOrIpAddress,23456;`

Comment: From which operating system and version are you connecting? If it's Linux/macOS, what version of OpenSSL is installed? To what version of SQL Server are you attempting to connect? Microsoft has been slowly (with glacial speeds) requiring connections to various Azure and Microsoft 365 properties have a minimum TLS 1.2 connection.

Comment: If you're connecting from a Linux/macOS client with a very old OpenSSL installation it may not have TLS 1.2 support. Or it could even have been disabled in the openssl.conf file by way of the `MaxProtocol` keyword. Ref: [config - OpenSSL CONF library configuration files](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html)

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning,
Thank you for your response. I am using  Azure Python Runbook. I am running this script from Automation Account.  I am trying to connect to Azure SQL Server. I mentioned the port[47072 and 1433]. Still facing the same err
or. SQL Server TLs Version is 1.2

Comment: As per the above error, it means that the sql/odbc driver version
is not compatible with TLS version. Can you try with Odbc 18 sql server (latest) with TLS 1.2?SQL Server ODBC driver 17 that ships with Windows does not support TLS 1.2. You can check this link for more information